# Views keep increasing on perf monitor

Tags: react-native

I have a tab based app (base on nativebase which uses react-native-router-flux for router). When I switch between tabs, the views on perf monitor keep increasing and so does the memory.

My question is what does this views means? After couple times of switch the views can go up to thousands and never decrease, which makes the app really slow. Is it possible to stop the views increasing when switching between scenes?

Comment: Very difficult to answer without having some code or working example. Consider adding it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this issue is caused by push scenes repeatedly with push method. In react-native-router-flux, scenes are switched by push method by default when Actions'key' is called. To avoid push every time we should use type="repeat":

```
<scene key="tab1" component={Com} type="repeat"/>
```